# scrollTo plugin with isotope

Tags: scrollto, jquery-isotope

My portfolio is located at http://www.visualise.ca/ and I am now working on a new version running isotope. It is available at http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise.

When I click on an image thumbnail which will load the post within the page I would like the page to scroll to the item (the clicked image thumbnail) using the jQuery scrollTo plugin and the following code:

```
$container.delegate( $itemString, 'click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('large');
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
        $('html,body').scrollTo(this, 800);
});
```

But after testing, it seems like the position of the item is always top:1 left:1 of the container (this would be 0 if the item didn't have a 1px border). Also when I use Firebug to inspect the item, the highlighted blue line is not on the item itself but located at top:1 left:1 of the container.

So I suspect that because of isotope all the plugins now thinks all the items are located at 0,0 (1,1 because the margins in my case).

What can I do in order to scroll properly?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the proper position of an item, relative to its container, using the following technique: set [`itemPositionDataEnabled: true`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled) in the options, and get the position using `.data('isotope-item-position')`.  For your code

```
$container.isotope({
  // options...
  itemPositionDataEnabled: true
});

$container.delegate( $itemString, 'click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      itemPosition = $this.data('isotope-item-position');
  $this.toggleClass('large');
  $container.isotope('reLayout');
  $('html,body').scrollTo( itemPosition.y, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test it as soon as I get the chance. I'll keep you posted. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`itemPositionDataEnabled` [has been removed in v2 of Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v1) and the above answer will no longer work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173587/itempositiondataenabled-in-jquery-isotope-v2-1) will help you achieve the same result with basic jQuery using `position` or `offset`.