# itemPositionDataEnabled in jquery isotope v2.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I just upgraded my isotope script to 2.1, but now the option itemPositionDataEnabled seems to not have any effect anymore. The `data("isotope-item-position")` just returns `undefined` now.

Here is the original documentation for the v1 script: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled

Any Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to get the position with [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) jquery method or [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
var p = $( "#element" );
var position = p.position();
alert( position.left + "," + position.top);
```

Answer (score 1):

From Isotope v2 docs:

itemPositionDataEnabled option removed. Item position is now accessible as it is set with left and top.

[Changes from v1 of isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v1)